# Show same Popup on two Views

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, layout, view

I am building a mvc 5 application.
I have two .cshtml views.
View1 with Layout1 and View2 with Layout2.
On Layout1 under some conditions i am showing a popup like

```
<input type="button" id="btnpopu" value="Open Modeless popup" onclick="ShowPopup();" />  
<script type="text/javascript">  
    ShowPopup = function () {  
        window.open('/Home/OpenPopup', "PopupWindow", 'width=400px,height=400px,top=150,left=250');  
    }  
</script>
```

When user changes to View2 by a button click or something like that, i need the popup window to stay in place.
Means still visible on Layout2
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

You should create the same popup at layout1 to layout2 `onload` also and send to it the specific conditions that you want, I think that the only way you can't keep state of view per request only by the same layout.

Comment: By creating the same popup at layout1 and layout2 ,i have to pass all the information from the created popup on layout1 to the new popup on layout2 when user changes the view.Thats to complicate.Is there not another way like creating a master layout  with the popup code,  on top of layout1 and layout2 ?

Comment: @assos40 nice idea, really i don't know, let's wait another replies.